# Pandas DataFrame Comprehensions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

## Problem: Add a new column to a DataFrame and populate with the values of a column from another DataFrame, depending on a condition, in one line of code similar to list comprehensions.

Example code:

I create a DataFrame called df with some pupil information

```
data = {'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'], 
        'year': [2012, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2014], 
        'reports': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index = ['Cochice', 'Pima', 'Santa Cruz', 
        'Maricopa', 'Yuma'])
```

Then a second DataFrame called df_extra which has a string representation of the year:

```
extra_data = {'year': [2012, 2013, 2014],
       'yr_string': ['twenty twelve','twenty thirteen','twenty fourteen']}
df_extra = pd.DataFrame(extra_data)
```

Now how to add the values `yr_string` as a new column to df where the numerical years match in one line of code?

I can easily do this with a couple of for loops, but would really like to know if this is possible to do in one line, similar to list comprehensions?

I have searched questions already on here, but there is nothing discussing adding a new column to an existing DataFrame from another DataFrame based on a condition in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) the dataframe on the year column.

```
df.merge(df_extra, how='left', on=['year'])
#     name  reports  year        yr_string
# 0  Jason        4  2012    twenty twelve
# 1  Molly       24  2012    twenty twelve
# 2   Tina       31  2013  twenty thirteen
# 3   Jake        2  2014  twenty fourteen
# 4    Amy        3  2014  twenty fourteen
```

Basically this says "pull the data from `df_extra` into `df` anywhere that the `year` column matches in `df`". **Note this will return a copy**, not modify the dataframe in place.

List comprehensions are still Python loops (that might not be totally technically accurate). With the [`pandas.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method, you get to take advantage of the vectorized, optimized backend code that Pandas uses to operate on its dataframes. Should be faster.

Comment: How would I modify inplace? Assign this merge to the original df or set copy=False? According to the documentation copy=False is not guaranteed to avoid making a copy

Comment: I don't think you can do a merge in place in Pandas. You would just assign the output either to a new dataframe or back to `df` and go from there.

Comment: Yes have been playing around with this. When I try and assign back to df it is not including the merge. There is an argument 'copy' which doesn't seem to do anything useful. I've created a question about this, as I want to avoid ending up with multiple DataFrames in memory

Comment: You can just do something like `merged_df = df.merge(...)` on one line and then `del df` and `del df_extra` after to free up memory. If they're big enough that you can't store that much in memory, then yeah, that's a whole other question :P