# A Better solution to check if dataframe value is in another dataframe and within specific date boundaries or ther specifications

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to check if each value in a column exist in another dataframe (df2) and if its date is at least 3 days close to the date in the second dataframe (df2) or if they meet other conditions.

The code I've written works, but I want to know if there's a better solution to this problem or a code that's more efficient

Exemple:

```
def check_answer(df):
    if df.ticket_count == 1:
        return 'Yes'
    elif (df.ticket_count > 0) and (df.occurrences == 1):
        return 'Yes'
    elif any(
            df2[df2.partnumber == df.partnumber]['ticket_date'] >= df['date']
    ) and any(
        df2[df2.partnumber == df.partnumber]['ticket_date'] <= df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3)
    ):
        return 'Yes'
    else:
        return 'No'

df['result'] = df.apply(check_answer, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using list comprehension.

Here's an example:
[list comprehension in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40646458/list-comprehension-in-pandas)

And if you need to create a copy of your data frame with news columns containing the result of your conditions, you can check this exemple: [Pandas DataFrame Comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55818345/pandas-dataframe-comprehensions)

I hope I could help

Best regards.